# Mocking signals function in unit test

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django version 4.2.6.

I have a file, `signals.py`, that includes a pre-save handler for my entity:

```
def do_stuff(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ... stuff...

pre_save.connect(do_stuff, sender=MyEntity)
```

... so that when an instance of `MyEntity` is either created or updated, the `do_stuff()` function is executed.

How do I mock `do_stuff()` in unit tests? I have a number of tests that create and update `MyEntity` instances, so `do_stuff()` is being called during the execution of the unit test. My implementation of `do_stuff()` is making a call to an external source amongst other functionality, so I want to mock it when the unit test runs.

I have tried declaring the following a part of my unit test:

```
@mock.patch("application.package.signals.do_stuff", autospec=True,)
```

... but when I execute the test, I can see that `do_stuff()` is still being executed.

Comment: A common pattern is to use a different settings file for your prod environment and your testing environment. You can set a parameter in the settings file that controls whether the external resource should be contacted. Then reference that setting parameter in the `do_stuff` function.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think the issue might be the `@mock.patch()` path. The patch has to be the module _importing_ what you want mocked. Like, if your views import `do_stuff`, you'd use `@mock.patch('application.package.views.do_stuff')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per bbayles' suggestion above, a solution was implemented where the code to call `do_stuff()` was only executed when it was deployed into an environment, rather than run locally or via unit tests.

I used `os.environ` to identify whether this was the case or not.